# Spring redis return 500 stackoverflow error

Tags: spring-boot, stack-overflow, spring-data-redis

I am trying to save some data to Redis in spring boot application.I am getting stackoverflow error while trying to insert the data into Redis.

I know there is some repetitive process going on here, but really couldn't understand where is the exception and the root cause for this.

RedisRepo:

```
public interface RedisRepo extends CrudRepository<RedisEntity,String> {

}
```

RedisObj:

```
public class RedisObj {

    @Id
    private Long field1;

    private String field2;

    private String field3;

    private String field4;

    private String field5;

    private UUID field6;

    private String field7;

    private String field8;

    private MyObject field9;

}
```

From Service:

```
redisRepo.save(ObjToRedis);
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.getElementTypeDescriptor(TypeDescriptor.java:331) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.equals(TypeDescriptor.java:470) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterCacheKey.equals(GenericConversionService.java:470) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(ObjectUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment.findInChain(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:648) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:506) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:267) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getEntryIfAvailable(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:253) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.get(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:234) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getConverter(GenericConversionService.java:255) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:189) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.toBytes(MappingRedisConverter.java:932) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeToBucket(MappingRedisConverter.java:748) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.lambda$writeInternal$2(MappingRedisConverter.java:631) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:355) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:583) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.lambda$writeInternal$2(MappingRedisConverter.java:625) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:355) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:583) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeCollection(MappingRedisConverter.java:719) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.lambda$writeInternal$2(MappingRedisConverter.java:610) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:355) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:583) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.lambda$writeInternal$2(MappingRedisConverter.java:625) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:355) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:583) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeCollection(MappingRedisConverter.java:719) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.lambda$writeInternal$2(MappingRedisConverter.java:610) ~[spring-data-redis-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, I am using the hiberante entity Object, (which is "MyObject" from the Post). Created a new Object and it worked Fine.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I've faced the same problem.